# Managing memory of polymorphic timed events with DLL

Tags: c++, dll

Here is my issue.

My Gui library that I made supports timed events. Basically, I have a class called TimedEvent which users inherit from. They then do:

```
addTimedEvent(new DerivedTimedEvent(...));
```

However given the nature of timed events, I manage the memory afterwards.

So when the timed event has done its thing, my library calls delete on it. Although it runs fine, that is because the exe and the library were both built with msvc 2008. I think I might have trouble if I have 2 versions of the runtime, one for the lib, and one for the exe.

What can I do to fix this? I can't create a factory because the derived type is on the exe side of things. I also cannot ask the user to call delete since they might not have a way to keep track of time, or know if the event was delayed for whatever reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting a Dellocator Functor object as construction parameter for your TimedEvent class. Now every client creating a derived class is expected to provied a Dellocator which you can call while deleting the object. You should also have default dellocator functor which simply deletes as a special case.

```
class base;

class Deallocator {
    void operator()(base* ptr) 
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
}

class base {
public:
base(Deallocator dealloc) 
{
    m_deleteFunc = dealloc;
}
~base() 
{
    m_deleteFunc(this);
}

private:
Deallocator m_deleteFunc;
}

int main
{
    Deallocator deletefunc;

    base baseObj(deletefunc);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Updated with a sample illustration for reference

Answer (score 0):

The boost::shared_ptr object can do it.  The reason being that the deleter is created at the construction site, so the appropriate version will be called even if you've got the c runtime fubar going on.

Comment: Is there a non-boost, non c++ 0x solution, I do not want to bring these into my library to keep it slim and portable

Comment: Yeah, you can rewrite it yourself.  It'll cost you as much to do that as it did the boost folks to get it done and work out all the kinks.  In the mean time you competitors, who aren't being silly, will beat you to the punch and probably end up with a better product to boot.